# Android cannot insert into database string with accents and blank space

Tags: php, android, mysqli

I´m having a problem with this string: "Não Vou". It means "I don´t go". I´m trying to insert it into database with php/json file.

When I remove blank space and ~ accent it works fine.

What I have tried:

- changed iso-8859-1 to utf-8;
- changed eclipse encoding to utf-8;
- changed print(json_encode($flag)) to print(json_encode('utf8_encode', $flag));
- Have read similar posts but any of them helped me.

  ```
  public class insertNo extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean>{

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

      ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("e_id", subString));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Não Vou", no));

      try{
          HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/includes/insert_counter.php");
          httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
          HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
          HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
          inputStream = entity.getContent();
          Log.e("pass 1", "connection success");
      }catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
          Log.e("Invalid IP", e.toString());
      }

      try {
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
          StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                
              stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
          }
          inputStream.close();
          result = stringBuilder.toString();
          Log.e("pass 2", "connection success");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
      }

      try {
          JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
          code = (json_data.getInt("code"));
          if (code==1) {
              Log.d("Insert success", result);
          } else {
              Log.d("Sorry son", result);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```

  }

php file

```
include_once("db_connect.php");

$e_id = $_REQUEST["e_id"];
$yes = $_REQUEST["Vou"];
$no = $_REQUEST["Não Vou"];
$maybe = $_REQUEST["Talvez"];

$flag['code']=0;


if(isset($yes)){
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE table1 SET yes = yes + 1 WHERE id='$e_id'");
    $flag['code']=1;
}else if(isset($no)){
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE table1 SET no = no + 1 WHERE id='$e_id'");
    $flag['code']=1;
}else if(isset($maybe)){
    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE table1 SET maybe = maybe + 1 WHERE id='$e_id'");
    $flag['code']=1;
}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: what kind of database?

Comment: @lispHK01 MySql utf8_unicode

Comment: In database you won't see the accents because get encoded, you will see them again when you retrieve the data. Also, in your update query if [id] is a int column, you should put $e_id instead of '$e_id'

Comment: @AlbertoFernández This is not the problem. I have 2 more classes inserting the data very well with "normal strings": "Vou" and "Talvez". Problem is accents and blank space between the 2 words

Comment: Please, confirm that your PHP variables are correct. [This states](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) that you cannot have extended characters, nor spaces in variable names. it should be either "Nao_Vou" or something. check the link for naming conventions.

Comment: @Bonatti It looks like it works. I was supposing that the string coming from strings.xml would interfere. But I don´t have to change it to be shown on the app layout. Just changing the string at "nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Nao_Vou", no));
" on the activity containing the class is enough. Thank you!

Comment: I will add an answer, please, mark it, then close the question if what you need is complete. `Qualquer coisa, pergunta que a gente ajuda.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), PHP variables should not contain special characters, or spaces, or anything out of

```
a letter is a-z, A-Z, and the bytes from 127 through 255 (0x7f-0xff).
```